Servlets problem with accessing subpages HTTP 404 Tomcat 10.1 java 11
I have just started to learn servlet technology, and I'm currently trying to create a very basic web application. Just some pages, trying this thing. I can reach the start page /index.html but I get 404 HTTP status code for other part:

Message:
The requested resource [/first] is not available
Description: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

My web.xml under WEB-INF is this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="4.0" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd">
</web-app>

My FirstServlet.java is this:
package servlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet("/first")
public class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        pw.println("<html>");
        pw.println("<body>");
        pw.println("Welcome to servlet");
        pw.println("</body>");
        pw.println("</html>");
        pw.close();
    }
}

The context path is /. I tried urlPatterns at WebServlet annotation. I'm trying it under IntelliJ IDEA Community, with Smart Tomcat plugin, with Tomcat 10.1.24 installed, and with Java 11. I ran mvn clean package.
After starting the application I can reach index.html with http://localhost:8080/ but I can't reach http://localhost:8080/first .
I'm trying to find the solution for some time but I wasn't able to do that. I read through the threads here (at least tried), too, but didn't find it. From a Dockerfile image I tried it with Tomcat 9.0.89 but I get the same / 404 http status code.
I would like to ask for your help in this question. If I can provide any useful additional relevant information, please let me know.
Thank you very much for your help in advance.

This code is very old servlet technology and it doesn't work with Tomcat 10.x. You can use it with Tomcat 9 or lower version.

I did something wrong somewhere when I tried that with Dockerfile. But now I tried and it works there. I don't know how could I set there the context path there to / . But that is another question.
Thank you very much for your answer.
